# Migrating hive collect_set query to apache crunch

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-crunch

How can I write apache crunch job equivalent to this hive query

`select A, collect_set(B) as C from table group by A` ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have done it with crunch properties Distinct class. It is already done.